# Switch from $AdS$ to $dS$ in quadratic gravity using $f(R)$ trick: problem

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, modified-gravity

I have some difficulties with effective quadratic gravity involving a cosmological constant with the "wrong sign". The following is the setup of my question.

Let's assume one has the following dimensionless action:
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4 x\sqrt{-g}\underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{2}m^4+\alpha m^2 R+\beta R^2\right.}_{\equiv f(R)}+\left.\frac{1}{60}R_{\mu \nu}R^{\mu \nu} \right) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Where $\alpha = \frac{1}{6}+\xi$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{2}\xi \left(\xi+\frac{1}{3} \right)+\frac{1}{120}$. Clearly, by expressing this action in terms of the Weyl quadratic invariant, and since the Bach tensor involves the Weyl tensor, an Anti-de Sitter space-time is a solution to the equations of motion associated with this action. Now, for some purpose I don't want to use the later representation of the action (1), I want it to stay as it is written in (1). Performing the usual f(R)-to-Scalar/tensor-theory trick I arrive at:
\begin{align}
S=&\frac{\gamma}{\zeta^2} \int d^4x \sqrt{-\tilde{g}}\left( \zeta^2 \tilde{R}-\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\mu \nu} \tilde{\partial}_\mu \Phi \tilde{\partial}_\nu \Phi-V(\Phi)\right.
\\
&\left.+\frac{\zeta^2}{\gamma}e^{-\frac{2 \Phi}{\sqrt{3}\zeta}} \left( \frac{1}{60}\tilde{R}_{\mu \nu} \tilde{R}^{\mu \nu}+\text{Coupl.}+W(\Phi) \right) \right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
With $\gamma$ and $\zeta$ two dimensionful constants coming from the definition of $\varphi=f'(\chi)=\gamma\, e^{\frac{\Phi}{\sqrt{3} \zeta}}$. $\text{Coupl.}$ stands for derivative non-minimal coupling terms, and $W(\Phi)$ is a potential involving four derivatives of $\Phi$. $m$ disappeared because of a redefinition of the conformal factor $e^{\frac{\Phi}{\sqrt{3} \zeta}} \leadsto e^{\frac{\Phi}{\sqrt{3} \zeta}-\ln\left( \frac{m^2}{90\alpha\gamma}\right)}$. Choosing the special phantom coupling $\xi=-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{30}+\delta$ for $0<\delta \ll 1$ on has:
\begin{equation}
    V(\Phi)\simeq -45 \gamma \zeta^2+\frac{3 \sqrt{10}}{4} \frac{\gamma}{\delta} \zeta^2\left(1-e^{-\frac{\Phi}{\sqrt{3}\zeta}} \right)^2 \tag{3}
\end{equation}
The second term is precisely the Starobinsky potential for $\zeta = \frac{\bar{m}_\text{Pl}}{\sqrt{2}}$. Assuming $1 \ll\gamma$, the dominant term in the action (2) is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\gamma}{\zeta^2} \int d^4x \sqrt{-\tilde{g}}\left( \zeta^2 \tilde{R}-\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\mu \nu} \tilde{\partial}_\mu \Phi \tilde{\partial}_\nu \Phi-V(\Phi)\right) \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Since $\delta \ll 1$, the constant term in the potential (3) is negligible when dealing with the potential only. So the inflation parameters are the same as for Starobinsky's theory.

I have a big problem because as you can see, at the beginning of the inflation, the field $\Phi$ is usually understood to be far from the origin, so $V(\Phi)\sim c^{ste}>0$, and then the problem is of a scalar field in de Sitter background, which would mean that we changed the space-time solution from AdS to dS...

**Question:** Have I been too optimistic in my approximations? In particular, are the terms neglected from (2) to (4) enforcing an AdS background solution? To me, it seems unlikely to be able to change from AdS to dS just by changing the representation of the theory, but I am not sure about where I go wrong with these equations.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is $\gamma,\zeta,S$, and where did $m$ go?

Second, beginning of inflation corresponds to large positive $V(\Phi)$, yes, but it is quasi-de-Sitter, not true de Sitter because $V$ and $\Phi$ still change with time, albeit slowly. The background is still AdS of course, since at the minimum the Starobinsky part vanishes, and the small negative cosmological constant is left.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've edited my post accordingly. How can the background be AdS if one has a quasi-de Sitter solution?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux the quasi-dS solution is not background solution in the strict sense, it is still dynamical because inflaton evolves with time. The "background" solution in this sense is defined when inflaton drops to the minimum. Then only the AdS part is left.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux although when talking about inflationary dynamics, the "background" is sometimes used in the weaker sense: because the inflaton is almost constant during inflation, we can take it as some effective VEV, and its potential will also be almost constant. In this sense, the background is dS, not AdS (if the AdS parameter is small).